# Number of ways to get $xy^2$ from $(x+y+5)^5$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to understand a proof of counting number of trees using the conclusion of Cayley's formula.

At the end they got a $(x+y+5)^5$ and they say that the number of ways to get $xy^2$ from this is $5 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 5^2 = 750 $ and I can't figure how. Can someone please explain?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more basic explanation.

You have $5$ terms being multiplied, each of which is $(x+y+5)$.

To get $xy^2$ from the product, you have to choose which term to take $x$ from, and which two terms to take $y$ from. The remaining terms will contribute $5\times 5=25$.

There are $5$ possibilities to choose the term providing $x$. Once this is fixed, the two terms providing $y$ can be chosen in $\binom42 = 6$ ways. Hence we have the $xy^2$ term appearing $5\times6=30$ times, each time with a coefficient of $25$. Hence the coefficient of $xy^2$ in the expansion is $30\times25=750$.

Comment: What do you mean by: "The remaining terms will contribute $5×5 = 25$" ?

Comment: If you picked one $x$ and 2 $y$s, you have to pick the 5 from the other two terms. So the coefficient of each $xy^2$ picked is 25, and you have to multiply the 25 by the number of $xy^2$ to get the final coefficient of $xy^2$.

Comment: But If I have chosen one x from a term like $(x+y+5)$ and 2 y's from another two terms, this will give me $5 × 5 × 5$ from both two that I have mentioned. Or doesn't that count somehow?

Comment: From each term, you can choose an x or a y or a 5, not all 3. And you consider all possibilities of picking. So you end up with xxxxx+xxxxy+xxxyy+xxxy5+... and so on. What you are interested in is how many terms are integer multiples of $xy^2$, these look like rearrangements of xyy55. This would be the terms xyy55, xy5y5, 5yx5y and so on. My answer explains how to calculate their number and the total contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $y^2$ in $$((x+5)+y)^5$$  is $$\binom52(x+5)^3$$

In how many we shall find $x$ in $(x+5)^3?$

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $a^\alpha b^\beta c^\gamma$ in $(a+b+c)^n$ is:

$$\frac{n!}{\alpha!\beta!\gamma!}$$

where $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=n$.

We want $\alpha=1,\beta=2,\gamma=2$, which is $\dfrac{5!}{1!2!2!}=30$.

As $c=5$, we end with $5^2.30=750$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+y+z)^n \to \dfrac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}x^{k_1}y^{k_2}z^{k_3} ,k_1+k_2+k_3=n\\$$
$$(x+y+5)^5 \to \dfrac{5!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}x^{k_1}y^{k_2}5^{k_3} ,k_1+k_2+k_3=5\\ \to xy^2 \to ,1+2+k_3=5 \to k_3=2\\ \dfrac{5!}{1!2!2!}x^{1}y^{2}5^{2} \\25\dfrac{5!}{1!2!2!}x^{1}y^{2}=25\times 30 xy^2$$